# How do i fix onBindViewHolder failed in nativescript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

i've been seeing this error on one of the pages on my nativescript app **(onBindViewHolder failed TypeError: cannot read property '0' of undefined)**, for some while now.
today it appeared on another page, a page that was working well.
the stack trace shows that it might have something to do with radlistview which both pages have.
please what could be causing this. if you need more information please let me know cause i have no idea.

i'm using nativescript core

Comment: Sounds like something with data binding, can you setup a Playground?

Comment: [link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=Syc3Xs&v=8) thanks. after the data loads on the first page, click on the item. then** try going back** from the second page, the error will come up.

Comment: @Manoj thats it

Comment: Looks like something specific to ListViewStaggeredLayout, I would suggest you to raise a ticket at https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues

Comment: @Manoj you are right, i changed to gridlayout and it works fine. thanks